# Create a tar file in a subdirectory of the directory to be archived

Tags: unix, tar, non-recursive

I'd like to create a tar file of all the files in a directory minus sub-directory's in that directory and place that tar file in one of the sub-directory's.  For example, I have several .txt files in /test and also another directory in /test called ArchivedFiles.  I'd like to tell the tar command to archive all of the .txt files and place it in /test/ArchivedFiles.
How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tar cf test/foo/test.tar -- `find test  -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -type f`
```

I think that should do what you want.

An option which will not work due to the age of your tar command is:

```
find test -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | tar -cf test/foo/test.tar --null --files-from -
```

You are having problems, so you can try the following commands:

```
tar cf test/foo/test.tar `find test  -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -type f`
echo tar cf test/foo/test.tar `find test  -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -type f`
tar c f test/foo/test.tar `find test  -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -type f`
find test  -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -type f
```

And pastebin the output so that we can see what is happening.

Given that find is very legacy as well, let us try the following:

```
tar cf test/foo/test.tar test/*.txt
```

Comment: This gives me: Usage: tar {c|r|t|u|x} [ bBdDEfFhilLXmNopRsSUvw[0-9] ]
           [ Blocks ] [ TarFile ] [ InputList ] [ ExcludeFile ]
           [ [ Feet ] | [ Feet@Density ] | [ Blocksb ] ] [-C Directory ] File ...

Comment: @Ben: Which command?  Also, what version of tar are you using?

Comment: @Ben: Also, do any of your .txt files have whitespace in them, or start with the - character?  If you are running the first version (probably you best best since you have such an old version of tar) then prefix the command with echo if you are still having problems and post the result so we can see what is going wrong.

Comment: option 1.  How do I check which version I'm using?

Comment: I believe it is an old version.  I don't have the ability to change this however.

Comment: option 2 gives me:
find: bad option -maxdepth
tar: illegal option -- -
Usage: tar -{c|r|t|u|x} [ -BdDEFhilmopRsUvw ] [ -Number ] [ -f TarFile ]
           [ -b Blocks ] [ -S [ Feet ] | [ Feet@Density ] | [ Blocksb ] ]
           [ -L InputList ] [-X ExcludeFile] [ -N Blocks ] [ -C Directory ] File ...
Usage: tar {c|r|t|u|x} [ bBdDEfFhilLXmNopRsSUvw[0-9] ]
           [ Blocks ] [ TarFile ] [ InputList ] [ ExcludeFile ]
           [ [ Feet ] | [ Feet@Density ] | [ Blocksb ] ] [-C Directory ] File ...

Comment: @Ben: I added some debugging commands which might help me understand what is happening.  Please pastebin the output so we can see what is happening.  If you have example syntax for a working tar command I can get this command to work with it, probably.

Comment: I should add that I'm trying to create a script that will be called from outside of the directory which I'm trying to archive.  I am replacing test with the full path name of my directory.  The first (new) option gives me:/FDM_EXTRACTS  -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -type f`
find: bad option -maxdepth

Comment: 2ND NEW OPTION:
find: bad option -maxdepth
tar cf /ssoutput/FDM_EXTRACTS/Archive/test.tar

Comment: 3RD OPTION: 
find: bad option -maxdepth
tar: /dev/rmt0: Permission denied

Comment: @Ben: OK, I added a new command which should work around the find problem (assuming that no directory ends in .txt).

Comment: 4th option: 
find: bad option -maxdepth

Answer (score 0):

The following command will work.  It will place any subdirectories into the tar but it doesn't put the *contents* of those subdirectories into the tar.  This means that if you put the tar into a subdir you won't have to worry about it putting itself inside itself inside itself...

For example, if you want to put all of the files which are in the current directory into a tar file called mytar.tar which is in a subdir called d1:

```
tar --no-recursion -cvf d1/mytar.tar *
```

Comment: From the usage message, it very much looks like OP is using a very old (legacy) tar.  Not GNU tar with all the fancy options.